# Calabash xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, calabash-ios

I am not able to generate Snippets with Regular Expressions in Xamarin.iOS Calabash.

Eg..

```
Feature:ABC
Given I launch my app
Then I should see text "Home"
```

Snippets generated:

```
Then(/^I should see text "Home"$/) do
pending #Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

I have tried passing "(.*)", "(.*?)" as well as "([^\"]*)"

Can anyone please tell me? Whether my installation process has missed out something or there is a problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

> Then(/^I should see text "Home"$/)

If you have a Step:

```
Then I should see text "Home"
```

The definition should be:

```
Then(/^I should see text "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|

end
```

What is actually happening?  And how are you running cucumber?